# There is only single longtable table in manuscript but why its number is displayed as "Table 2"?

Tags: longtable

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preprint,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}%to get pdf zoomed to 100%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}%for \mathfrak{g}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
 \hline\hline
 % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
 \\ $N_a$ & $\text{Nor}_{\mathfrak{g}}\left(N_a\right)/N_a$ & Sub--algebras \\\\\hline\hline
 $e_1$&$\{e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5\}$
 \\\hline\hline\end{longtable}\captionof{table}{Classification of algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\,L_5\oplus L_4 \oplus L_3$.}\label{classi}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Longtable increases the table counter, with the intention that you use `\caption` within the environment, and then you have used `\captionof{table}` outside the environment.

Either change

```
\end{longtable}\captionof{table}{...}
```

to

```
\caption{...}\end{longtable}
```

or, for special circumstances where you really need no caption in the table, you could use

```
\end{longtable}\addtocounter{table}{-1}\captionof{table}{...}
```

Comment: Where should I place caption then ?

Comment: @IgotiT I added the code in an edit which I think crossed with your comment, is it clearer now?

Comment: Ok ok, I am sorry, I got it.